How urgent of a fix on roof?

My house is about one hundred years old.  I went up in the attic for a simple HVAC fix, and noticed this rot.  It seems to be the source of a very slow leak--like almost imperceptible damage around around a chimney.  The roof was replaced in 2016 by previous owners.  I'm having a couple of roofing companies drop by this week to give a quote.  I would appreciate some advice on a couple of points:

How urgent is this damage?  Money is tight, so is there a way I can DIY it from the attic with some sort of patch and/or sealant?  That could give me time to save up more in my emergency fund for other roof work (like adding a vent to a bathroom, chimney work, etc.).

When I meet with the roofing companies, are there other things I should mention or bring up? (Sorry for the vagueness, but I don't know what I don't know).  This is my first time dealing with a roofing issue.


Any advice would be appreciated.

"How urgent" is a lottery... Did you buy the winning ticket?

Must fix leaks from where the water comes in, there is no fix from inside the attic.  If water comes in, it goes somewhere down, where it does not dry as fast, so mold and greater rot might be found in the walls/ceiling.

The black marks are absolutely signs of water infiltration ( You knew that).
The question is has the wood rotted or is this the first manifestation of a leak and the area affected is only on the surface.
Use a screwdriver to probe the area. Anything soft and /or crumbly will indicate the wood has some extensive rot and needs to be replaced. A roofing company worth it's while will recommend that part of the roof be torn off, the wood replaced and recovered and shingled.  There isn't anything you can do from the inside.
If you are lucky and the screwdriver probing does not show rot through the wood, you can thoroughly treat the area with 50/50 bleach and water to kill the wood destroying organisms.  ( cover any areas of the attic where the solution will be dripped.)
You then need to look for the leak.  It could be just a nail pop that allows a slight bit of rain. Sometimes this can only happen in the event of a long drizzle or only on downpours. So, be diligent in looking during varying rain events. If you can do so safely, look on the roof for any ripped shingles or humps that are signs of raised nails. Also look for any flashing that need caulked.
If your wood is still solid and you can kill the wood destroying organisms, but not get on the roof, you can ask the roofing company to look for the leak and enact repairs rather than a complete tear-off.
A final possibility is the roofing company could tell you if a roof overlay is a possibility, if allowed in your area. This is shingling over the existing shingles and is only a possibility if the roof decking has no rot.
